# Calculate $\int_{S}^{} \frac{r\cdot n}{r^{3}}dS $ where $S$ is a surface

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

Let $\mathbf{n}(x,y,z) $ be the vertical vector on the surface $S$, where $S$ is $$\frac{1}{9}x^{2} + \frac{1}{16}y^{2}+\frac{1}{12}(z-1)^{4} = 1$$ and let $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z) $. Then calculate $$\int_{S}^{} \frac{r\cdot n}{r^{3}}dS $$

I have hard times trying to understand what this integral is. Is it equal to $\int_{S}^{}\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}dS$? I tried to use surface integral and I tried to use parameters for this surface but it seems so difficult. I don't think that's the point in this exercise. I think that I have to notice something that I can't find.

Comment: Use the divergence theorem

Comment: Surely $\mathbf{n}(x,y,z)$ is the normal vector to $S$. Is that what you mean by "vertical vector"

Comment: @B.Martin Which function should I take?

Comment: $\oint_{S}\frac{r\cdot n}{r^3}dS=\oint_{S}(\vec{\nabla}\frac{1}{r})d\vec{S}=\int_V\Delta(\frac{1}{r})dV=4\pi\int_V\delta(\vec{r})dV=4\pi$ if the point $(0,0,0)$ is inside the body, otherwise $=0$